# asp.net calling button click event that i created

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, ispostback

I am writing a web app in asp.net.
I have an aspx page that call a class (Test) that Generates a button and return the button.
The class constructor get the function that the button click event should activate (userClickOnButton)
 and
insert to the button.click += EventHandler("the name of the function (userClickOnButton)");

the problem is that in the aspx behind code i use IsPostBack (cant take it off , need this Condition) and when i click on the button the progrem does not go to the event i created for the button, but when i take off the IsPostBack Condition the program does go to the event i created (the function userClickOnButton).

my code is:
aspx code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Test test = new Test(userClickOnButton);
        Button button = test.AddButton();
        cell.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}

private void userClickOnButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ModalPopupExtenderSelectFilds.Show();
}
```

my class

```
public class Test
{

Action<object, EventArgs> m_ButtonClickActivateFunction;

public Test(Action<object, EventArgs> func) 
{
    m_ButtonClickActivateFunction = func;
}

public Button AddButton()
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "select";
    button.ID = "buttonID";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(m_ButtonClickActivateFunction);

    return button;
}
```

need help to activate the event without taking out the IsPostBack Condition

thanks

Comment: without postback how the server know about it? However you can do it in a manner that it seems without postback with the help of Ajax

Comment: I can only show you the http://www.asp.net/ajax. You're the one that has to walk through it.

Comment: delete the if(!IsPostBack) in the Page_Load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think asp.net doesn't handle clicks on buttons that no longer exist. Since on postback you don't recreate the button and the button therefore does no longer exist in the controls collection of the page, the event is not handled.

Handling of the event happens after `Page_Load`, so `Page_Load` should have recreated the button.

Have a look here as well: [Asp.Net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)